# Converting string to number doesn't work outputs 0's

Tags: c#, string, numbers, streamreader

I am trying to write 100 random numbers into a file then read the file into a array and then sort the array and then write it out. If I set the array length to 101 then the code work if it is higher it doesn't work and just outputs 0's. It just seems that for some reason if the array length is above the actual array length the covert function just outputs 0's.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Filesort
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random rng = new Random();
            int[] numbers = new int[1000];
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:/c#/sitekjekokot.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(rng.Next(1, 101));
                    }
                    sw.WriteLine("end");
                }
            }
            int size = 0;
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:/c#/sitekjekokot.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
                {
                    string number = "sitek";
                    while(true)
                    {
                    number = sr.ReadLine();
                        if (number != "end")
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        if (number == null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("sitejekokot");
                        }
                        Console.Write(number);
                        numbers[size] = Convert.ToInt32(number);
                        size++;
                        Console.WriteLine(numbers[size]);
                    }
                }
            }

            Array.Sort(numbers);
            for (int z = 0; z < size; z++)
            {
            Console.WriteLine(numbers[z]);
            
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't need to write "end" to end a file, you can just.. stop writing the file. It actually makes things unnecessarily complex to write "end". I think you meant to have a logic of `=="end"` not what you have

Answer (score 0):

You `break` *too early*, on the very 1st line

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
{
    string number = "sitek";
    
    while(true)
    {
         number = sr.ReadLine();
         
         // On the very 1st line (which is random number, not "end")... 
         if (number != "end")
         {
             // ... you break, i.e. stop reading file
             break;
         }
         ...
```

I suggest using `File` class instead of `Stream`s and *Linq* for querying.

Create `100` random numbers and write them into file:

```
Random rng = new Random();

File.WriteAllLines(@"C:/c#/sitekjekokot.txt", Enumerable
  .Range(1, 100)
  .Select(i => rng.Next(1, 101).ToString())
  .Concat(new string[] {"end"}));
```

Read all numbers from file until `"end"` mark, sort the items and materialize as an array:

```
int[] numbers = File
  .ReadLines(@"C:/c#/sitekjekokot.txt")
  .TakeWhile(line => line != "end")
  .Select(line => int.Parse(line))
  .OrderBy(number => number) 
  .ToArray();
```

Write down all the `numbers`:

```
foreach (var number in numbers)
  Console.WriteLine(number);
```